# Getting raw reponse after fetching backbone collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have an json response from the server like this for  backbone collection

```
 {
       "Heading":[
          {
             "heading1":"heading1",
             "heading2":"heading2",
             "heading3":"heading3",
             "heading4":"heading4",
             "heading5":"heading5",
             "heading6":"heading6",
             "heading7":"heading7"
          }
       ],
       "Data":[
          {
             "column1":98310,
             "column2":"spl",
             "column3":"sreedhar Laptop",
             "column4":"LAPTOP",
             "column5":"ACTIVE",
             "column6":true,
             "column7":"c56e4b92-debe-4c8e-9472-bbb6a322346d"
          },
          {
             "column1":196609,
             "column2":"NLP",
             "column3":"NLP testing..",
             "column4":"LAPTOP",
             "column5":"ACTIVE",
             "column6":true,
             "column7":"7fe2efd4-b93b-4ea8-98a4-7a75d77efb77"
          },
          {
             "column1":262146,
             "column2":"venky",
             "column3":"venkyLaptop",
             "column4":"DESKTOP",
             "column5":"INACTIVE",
             "column6":false,
             "column7":"2e512b95-e2b3-414c-8b40-3bd00b626ae4"
          }
       ]
    }
```

So What I want is to pass only the Data aray for the collection so I have used parse method like this

```
Customer = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: customerModel,

    url: function () {

        return Config.serviceURL("getCusData");


    },
    parse: function (response) {

        return response.Data;
    }


});
```

This is working perfectly but Now I want that Heading array also after I apply fetch So how can I get this Heading array on calling fetch??

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule that says that `parse` can't stash parts of `response` in `this`. For example:

```
parse: function(response) {
    this.headings = response.Heading;
    return response.Data;
}
```

Then later the collection can look at `this.headings` to see the `response.Heading` values.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/k9aUa/

If you're using other methods (such as `reset`) to populate your collection then you might need to override those to reset `this.headings`.